# First create new document before Serialize

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc

Im working with C++ MFC. Its a MDI application.
Whenever I open a file, the serialize function gets called. But the problem is, the program first serializes the veriables, and then creates a new file. I'd like to have it the other way.

Can anyone explain me how to do this?

Comment: You need to call your `new file` functionality before calling the `serialize` functionality.  Can't help any more than that without seeing your code!

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoints in MFC's CDocument::OnOpenDocument to see what is happening. That is where the MFC framework calls Serialize. You can override this function in your CDocument-derived class and do anything you want.